# Remove repeating special characters using regular expression if present alone but not when surrounded by words or numbers

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

How can I remove special characters from a string IFF it is present as an individual. I am trying to work on a tweet author classification model and my idea is that some people use special characters as a trademark and it can help model in better judgement such as

```
P!nk
A$AP
```

are trademark for two individual singers. I want to remove individual and repeating special characters such as

```
whatt??
This is Good. I want both dots removed.
I'm thinking....
```

But do not want to remove `#hashtag_for_life` or something like this

I have used

```
re.sub(r'([\W_])\1+',' ','hi my % na$me is @shady #for_life')
```

but failing in individual. Can someone please provide a solution.

**EDIT:EXAMPLE**

How can I convert

```
'p!nk & A$AP are 2 singers..... what? are the b0th rappers? ? ? NO!! #singer ##rapper @shady'
```

to

```
'p!nk A$AP are singers what are the b0th rappers NO #singer #rapper @shady'
```

It means that individual numbers are gone, individual special characters gone, trailing special characters are gone and repeating special characters are changed to single special characters which are either in the middle or at the beginning of a word.

Comment: Can you provide string where your solution is failing? and how is it failing?

Comment: I want to remove this individual **%** or any special character which is present individually in my string.

Comment: what do you mean by individiually if you can give 2 or 3 examples

Comment: @Pygirl please take a look at the edit. I hope it covers everything. I am not expecting a single line code though but no idea either.

Comment: If you expect `individual special characters gone`, the `&` just after `p!nk` should be removed.

Comment: @tshiono sorry my bad. it was copy paste problem. Until someone gives me a solution can you please tell me how do I either put a space or completely remove a special character after a word. ```helloo!!!``` can either be ```hello``` or ```hello !!!``` so that I can use two steps in the second case to remove special character.

Comment: You need to define which characters are "special characters". It need not be a complete list, merely a few to allow the reader to know which characters in your examples are special. For example, it appears that `!` is not a special character, but if it is not, why did you removed both in `NO!!`? There's no need to inform readers that you have edited your question, just rewrite it as though you were working on a draft of a paper.

Comment: How how you plan to use the regex (classification system, singers, etc.) is irrelevant. Just start by saying you want to do certain things to a string. Define special characters (e.g, "characters in the string `?#^`") and then state the requirements, perhaps in point form (e.g., "convert the following to empty strings: 1) strings of one or more digits; 2) special characters that are neither preceded nor followed by the same special character ...). Then give examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please try the f0llowing:

```
import re
str = 'p!nk & A$AP are 2 singers..... what? are the b0th rappers? ? ? NO!! #singer ##rapper @shady'

str = re.sub(r'(?<=\s)[\W\d](?=(\s|$))', '', str)
str = re.sub(r'(?<=\w)\W+(?=(\s|$))', '', str)
str = re.sub(r'(\W)\1+(?=\w)', r'\1', str)

print(str)
```

Output:

```
p!nk A$AP are singers what are the b0th rappers NO #singer #rapper @shady
```

- `(?<=\s)[\W\d](?=(\s|$))` matches a single non-alphabetical or digit
  character surrounded by whitespaces or at the end of the line.
- `(?<=\w)\W+(?=(\s|$))` matches a single non-alphabetical character following
  a word.
- `(\W)\1+(?=\w)` matches two or more consecutive non-alphabetical characters
  preceding a word.

Comment: one more thing, it is not removing the trailing ```!```.  as in ```hello!```

Comment: @Deshwal thank you for your prompt feedback. I've added a small explanation about the regex. Hope it will help.

Comment: @Deshwal I've corrected the regex to match a special character at the end of the line. Would you please test it?